# SSH Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm new using servers In my pc I don't have any problem using Apache Spark. Normally I use IntelliJ for running the code.

I tried in the external server ssh to run a project and I have the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$assertOnDriver(SparkSession.scala:1086)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:902)
>     at com.p53.main(p53.java:42)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 8 more

When I run in the terminal (/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-shell), Spark runs well.

My pom dependencies are:

```
dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The pom plugins:

```
plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

I know I'm doing something wrong or something is missing, but I just dont figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Spark is built against Hadoop 2.7, not 3.2, and it's transitive, so you don't need to mention it in the POM

Comment: I remove it and still doesn't work, nether Hadoop 2.7 @cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH.

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`
```

Comment: the classpath will be to download directly hadoop or to the Hadoop Jars in spark? Thx

Comment: @KarenciaGárate - hadoop jars in spark.

Comment: I add this amd still have the same problem. My bash is: export SPARK_HOME/home/kgarate/spark    export HADOOP_HOME=/home/kgarate/hadoop  export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=/home/kgarate/spark/jars/*

Comment: But I also tried with my own hadoop classpath @Jerin